# Concept behind elementary operation on matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, random-matrices

What is the concept behind matrix elementary operation? 
When we try to find inverse of a matrix using elementary operations we write 
$$A=A*I$$ 
If we are going to solve by column elementary operation 
And 
$$A=IA$$ if it's row elementary operation

I am not able to understand the concept behind it.

Why only these three elementary transformation exist? 
And how are these derived?

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's solved now....How to set it as solved?

Comment: Thanks https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Comment: Thanks mate  @gimusi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is that:

**right multiplication** $Av$ correspond to a columns combination of $A$ by the entry values of v

**EG**

$A\cdot e_1=A\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\.\\0\end{bmatrix}$= first column of $A$

**left multiplication** $Av$ correspond to a row combination of $A$ by the entry values of v

**EG**

$e_1^T\cdot A=[1,0,0,...,0]\cdot A$= first row of $A$

Comment: Thanks ...please answer the other question as well...the reasoning behind elementary transformation and the derivation as to why we have only 3 elementary operations?

Comment: @lancer take a look here it is explained quite well, if you need some hel do not hesitate to ask me, thanks! http://stattrek.com/matrix-algebra/elementary-operations.aspx

Comment: Thank you :) it helped me ...so how i comprehend these elementary operations are- these are operations on matrix such that at each step your LHS = RHS...ie even after the elementary operations your independent matrix may not be same but your LHS will always be equal to RHS